# How to allow user to adjust size of control

Tags: c#

Simple question, but I didn't know what's the keywords to Google.

Suppose we want to adjust the height of the taskbar on Windows. When u place the mouse cursor at the edge of it, the cursor will change to an up and down arrow meaning that the taskbar is resizable.

How do I get that cursor to come out in C#?

Is there a control for it? Or do I have to check if the mouse is on the edge of the control, if it is change cursor. On click resize according to the difference?

Comment: Thread on MSDN forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9058f178-6b25-4c44-8919-58740da2c1d8/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cb77f081-af22-4d41-966b-9ee30d6364b9) and [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771714.aspx).

Comment: If it is WinForms we are talking about, this is very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308987/resizing-controls-at-runtime Link in the answer looks useful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ResizeControlsRuntime.aspx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would put a splitter control onto the form, set it to horizontal, then put the control you want to be sizeable (taskbar, whatever) inside the splitter, go into the dock settings and dock it to all sides.